# Confluent HDFS Connector

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I want to move kafka log file to hadoop log file. So i make follow HDFS Connector Configuration

> /quickstart-hdfs.properties

```
name=hdfs-sink 
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
tasks.max=1 
topics=kafka_log_test 
hdfs.url=hdfs://10.100.216.60:9000 
flush.size=100000 
hive.integration=true 
hive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9083 
schema.compatibility=BACKWARD 
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat 
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.Hour‌​lyPartitioner
```

> /connect-avro-standalone.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=localhost:9092

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false

offset.storage.file.filename=/tmp/connect.offsets
```

When i run the HDFS Connector, just writes avro schema in .avro file. Not data.

> /kafka_log_test+0+0000000018+0000000020.avro

```
 avro.schema {"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"f1","type":"string"}],"connect.version":1,"connect.name":"myrecord"}
```

Topic have lots of data  but confluent hdfs connector doesn't move data to hdfs.

How can i do that to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, unless the messages are otherwise compacted or expired between offsets 18 and 20 then the file containing the name `0+0000000018+0000000020` will have 2 records from partition 0.

You should use `tojson` command of `avro-tools` rather than `getmeta`.

Or you can use Spark or Pig to read that file.

---

You might also want to verify the connectors is continuing to run after starting it because setting `hive.metastore.uris=thrift://localhost:9083` on a machine that is not the Hive Metastore Server will cause the Connect task to fail. The URI should be the actual host for Hive, just as you've done for the NameNode.

---

Also, it shouldn't be possible to get a `.avro` file extension with `format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat` anyway, so you might want to verify you are looking in the correct HDFS path. Note: Connect writes to a `+tmp` location temporarily before writing the final output files.